# Redirect all requests to non www ssl https

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I need a very simple .htaccess to redirect all requests from

http://puaction.com

http://www.puaction.com

https://www.puaction.com

to

https://puaction.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root (for the `puaction.com` domain):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://puaction.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Perfect! Sorry that I can't vote up! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This article has some nice SEO tricks: http://evolvedigitallabs.com/blog/htaccess-tricks-for-seo/

See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/the-great-dub-dub-dub-debate.html for further discussion